# Create Sandbox C#

Tags: c#, sandbox

are there any tutorials out there on how to create a sandbox using C#?

I would like to personalize my own one, thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific?  What do you mean by 'sandbox?'  Do you want a sandbox to host apps in, or something else?

Comment: What do you mean by 'sandbox'?

Comment: Shame it isn't possible to decrease points in comments. Most above are completely useless.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Study up on using [AppDomains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx). Here's some code [examples](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0240__Assembly/0020__AppDomain.htm).

Comment: Thanks a more appropriate answer than the one's above :)

Comment: It's shocking how quick SO users are to take jabs at a less than perfect question. Yes, yours is a bit on the vague side. However, discouraging new members with smart remarks does nothing but cast an unnecessary shadow on the community. Sorry you had to deal with that.

Answer (score 1):

We just recently used the [MonoSandbox](http://www.mono-project.com/MonoSandbox) for Security reasons.

I don't know if it works with standard Microsoft's CLR, or if it is specific to the Mono implementation, but I think it works better than just a custom sanbdbox using AppDomains, and since the source code is open you can probably find a way to make it work for you.

The best documentation I have found for the MonoSandbox is here: http://www.mono-project.com/MonoSandbox

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking at [Code Access Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/930b76w0(VS.80).aspx).